# What is the difference between Appium-XCUITest-Driver and appium-dotnet-driver?

Tags: appium

From the Appium website, it is stated that Appium is an open source, cross-platform test automation tool for native, hybrid and mobile web and desktop apps. For a specific case, you would need a specific driver. For example, IOS test will need XCUITestDriver, and UIAutomator2 for Android. Sounds good.

But from my understanding, appium-dotnet-driver is also an Appium client library that is needed if you write your test in .Net. So is appium-dotnet-driver is just a subset of Appium-XCUITest-Driver ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Appium dot net driver** is an extension of the Selenium C# client. It has all the functionalities of the regular driver, but it add Appium specific methods on top of this. 
more read [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver)

**Appium-XCUITest-Driver** is developed by appium for only iOS environment when apple deprecated UIAutomation unit test framework and added new XCTest library for unit testing.

So as per my understanding dotnetdriver is not a subset of Appium-XCUITest-Driver instead dotnet driver can be used for Android + iOS both environments but Appium-XCUITest-Driver is specifically written for iOS version >10